# Can't make Siri Shortcuts work in macCatalyst app

Tags: sirikit, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to port my iOS app to Mac using macCatalyst, and I'm having problem with Siri Shortcuts. The code complies and runs, but when I try to add shortcut using `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController` I'm seeing 'Shortcuts unavailable.'

Using
`INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getAllVoiceShortcuts` returns error  `[Intents] -[INVoiceShortcutCenter getAllVoiceShortcutsWithCompletion:]_block_invoke Error from -getVoiceShortcutsWithCompletion: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application."`

Any ideas what's I'm doing wrong? Same code works perfectly fine on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The Intents framework is unavailable at runtime on macOS except for WidgetKit support. The APIs are available at compile time in the Mac Catalyst environment to reduce the amount of changes required to compile for Mac Catalyst. Calling into the APIs as part of the shared code path between iOS and Mac Catalyst is fine, they will just return an error for Mac Catalyst, as you're seeing.

Posted 11 hours ago by edford 